# Is there a way to fake specific event listeners when testing Laravel?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

I have an event with multiple listeners, one of them sends a notification. I would like to test that without running irrelevant listeners.

```php
// EventServiceProvider

protected $listen = [

    ProductionStarted::class => [
        StartOtherTasks::class,
        SendNotifications::class,
    ],
];
```

Here's a snippet from test. The issue here when dispatching the event, all of its listeners are being run (`StartOtherTasks` listener in this case) I don't want it to listen.

```php
public function test_starting_production_sends_notification()
{
    event(new ProductionStarted());

    Notification::fake();

    Notification::assertSentTo(
        $notifiable,
        NotifyBatchStarted::class,
    );
}
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/best-way-to-test-event-listeners

Comment: You do not do this, you just do a feature test and fake the events so it does not trigger listeners, and if you want to specifically test a listener, you just create a unit test and run the listener with the event in the test, that's it !

Answer (score -2):

you can trigger a specific listener like this

```
$listener = new StartOtherTasks();
$listener->handle(new ProductionStarted());
```